# Why are my GtkEntry icon tooltips not working?

Tags: gtk, gjs, gtkentry

I have define a GtkEntry in GJS like so:

```
let myEntry = new Gtk.Entry({
    hexpand: true,
    placeholder_text: "Type here...",
    secondary_icon_name: "dialog-error-symbolic",
    secondary_icon_tooltip_text: "Send...",
    secondary_icon_activatable: true,
    secondary_icon_sensitive: true
});
```

However, the tooltip never shows. No error is printed to log and I've combed the docs for properties and functions, am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

This is a known bug in `get_icon_at_pos()` which is used by the `::query-tooltip` handler and a fix has been pushed [upstream](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780938#c12) by Daniel Boles on 2017-07-31.

Comment: I've tried with a simple example in Glade and it didn't work too. Probably a bug. If the Entry has a tooltip, it will show that but the primary or secondary icon tooltips are not shown. Maybe we should file a bug in bugzilla

Comment: Gah, I think that's my third one this week! Thanks for letting me know it's not just me, and now that I look a report already exists here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780938

Comment: I'm not even using GJS, so I'm not suggesting this is a solution. Did you see [this example](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/tooltip.js.html.en) on the developer's site? It seems that there is some extra option (has_tooltip) to be set to True.

Comment: @jcoppens tks for the input. Tooltips work, the question regards tooltips on GtkEntry primary and secondary icons. These icons have a tooltip but ain't working.